# To select an element from the list based on probability in Python

Tags: python, probability, context-free-grammar

I am writing a Python code to generate random sentences using context free grammar.

Each non-terminal/terminal symbol has a weight associated with it.

Currently I am using `random.choice()` to select an element from the `defaultdict(list)`. This gives me an output giving all the elements of the list an equal probability.

How can I select an element if probability of each element is different?

I have a context free grammar in the form of:
Weight    NT     NT/T

Example:
70    NounPhrase    A 
30    NounPhrase    B

So probability of 1st NP to get selected would be 70/(70+30) and second would be 30/(70+30). So how can I use this concept with random in Python?